# What is causal inverse of a system?

Tags: matlab, linear-systems, z-transform, control-systems, causality

Let's say that I have a system $H(z)$. What is causal inverse and how do I compute the causal inverse of $H(z)$?

Answer (score 3):

The inverse $G(z)$ of a system $H(z)$ is simply

$$G(z) = \frac{1}{H(z)}$$

The poles of $G(z)$ are the zeros of $H(z)$ and the zeros of $G(z)$ are the poles of $H(z)$.

$G(z)$ is only stable if the poles are inside the unit circle, which implies that for $G(z)$ to be stable, $H(z)$ needs have all it's zero inside the unit circle, i.e. it's minimum phase.

So if $H(z)$ is causal, stable and minimum phase, it's inverse is also causal stable and minimum phase.

Comment: $G(z)$ is not causal if $H(z)$ has more poles than zeros. Namely, $G(z)$ would then have more zeros than poles. One could compensate for this using a delay (poles at zero).